# How to continue calling __init__ funtion until certain condition meet?

Tags: python, loops, init

Take the below code for an example.

```py
import random
class test:
    def __init__(self):
        x = random.choice([1,2,3])
        print(x)
        if x == 2:
            pass
```

What I want to do here is that when x equals 2 then run the function again and get the different value of x.  Therefore whenever I call the `test` class it always assigns the x value other than 2.

> NOTE: We must run the `random.choice()` in the `__init__` and always get the value other than **2**, it's okay to run the `__init__` as many times as we want unless we get the different value.
> The value of `x` is random.

What I have tried

```py
class test:
    def __init__(self):
        x = random.choice([1,2,3])
        if x != 2:
            self.x = x
        else:
            test()
```

Comment: I don't think you should call `__init__` recursive. But how about a while-loop? And, if you don't want 2, you could of course just remove it from the list of choices Another option is to create the loop around the creation of the object

Comment: Yeah while loop worked smoothly. and I know one should not use the `__init__` recursive. I was just curious to know how to implement such a task. Although removing value from the list of choices is not the option haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**
Implementing the while loop sounds a good idea.
Try this:

```py
import random
class test:
    def __init__(self):
        x = random.choice([1,2,3])
        loop = 0
        while x == 2:
            x = random.choice([1,2,3])
            loop += 1
            if loop >= 5:
                x = False
```

It is impossible to return any value from the `__init__()` function, since the function is supposed to return None, therefore I have set the x value to False, if it is something you'd like,

Comment: I like the answer and I think it works but I would suggest putting this kind of functionality in it's own method. The __init__ method is intended to run just once and mostly it should not contain anything that potentially runs forever, since initialisation won't finish. If you were to inherit from this class and run the super on the child's init, it might get stuck.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I really wonder can we set the limit here. For example, execute the code maximum 5 times to get the value other than  **2**, and if not found return `FALSE`

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but I have updated the code, please have a look!

Answer (score 1):

You really don't want to be calling **init** recursively. If you're using Python 3.8+ there's a neat way to fulfil your requirement.

```
class test:
  def __init__(self):
    while (x := random.choice([1,2,3])) == 2:
      pass
```

At some point the *while* loop will terminate when x is either 1 or 3

Comment: Hmm... I like this answer. I have not seen the use case of `:=` before. but I believe it's helping python to understand two equals to signs at the same time.

Comment: It's the so-called "walrus operator". Read about it [here](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html)